# Convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k k!}{(2k)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We want to check if the following converges (absolutely):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k k!}{(2k)!}$$

I have seen the following solution on the internet, but it's too complex for me to understand

[image]

Is there an "easier" way to do this?

Comment: Did you try ratio test (or root test if you want to be a rebel)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{2^{k+1}(k+1)!(2k)!}{2^kk!(2k+2)!}=\frac{2(k+1)}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}\to 0$$ as $k\to \infty$. So by the ratio test it converges

Answer (score 1):

Try the ratio test. Consider
$$R=\left|\frac{\frac{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}{(2(k+1))!}}{\frac{2^kk!}{(2k)!}}\right|$$
Notice that $R\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. That is
$$\rho= \lim_{k\to \infty} R = 0.$$
Since $\rho<1$, then the series
$$\sum \frac{2^kk!}{(2k)!}$$
converges.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the root test
using
$(n!)^{1/n}
\approx \frac{n}{e}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\dfrac{2^k k!}{(2k)!}\right)^{1/k}
&=2\dfrac{ k!^{1/k}}{((2k)!)^{1/k}}\\
&\approx 2\dfrac{ k/e}{\left(((2k)!)^{1/(2k)}\right)^2}\\
&\approx 2\dfrac{ k/e}{(2k/e)^2}\\
&= \dfrac{e}{2k}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

so the sum converges.